# In Laravel, how can I access all files inside of the storage directory?

Tags: laravel, image, file, directory

I have a Laravel application with a storage/app/icons directory, inside of which is about 200 files/images:

[image]

My method to get retrieve all files inside of this folder is:

```
    public function index()
    {
        $icons = public_path('icons');
        $allIconsInsideFolder = Storage::allFiles($icons);
        return view('instapage', compact('allIconsInsideFolder'));
    }
```

However, it doesn't work correctly. How can I change the controller function so that it retrieves all files inside of the storage/app/icons directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should pass the right path to the Storage::allFiles() method,
witch look like it is in storage path in app folder then icons folder

please try:

```
$icons = storage_path('app/icons');
$allIconsInsideFolder = Storage::allFiles($icons);
```

or:

```
$icons = storage_path('app/icons');
$allIconsInsideFolder = File::files($icons);
```

or

```
  $icons = storage_path('app/icons');
    $allIconsInsideFolder = scandir($icons);
```

it should work

Comment: Thank you for your help, would you happen to know how to display all files in a blade template? as in, what should go in :src ? :src= "$icons" ?

Comment: you can put all files in array and send it to your view as parameter, and make simple foreach